# Convert datetime2 to string("dd/MM/yyyy") in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, type-conversion

I have a datetime2 column in the database.I'm trying to fetch that from database and I want to display it in the view as string.

I tried: `dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

But it gave an error.

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I tried `String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);` also, even this throwed an error.

[image: Error]

Comment: What error did it give?

Comment: show me the error please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I realize your problem, after you posted the screenshot. Some functions aren't allowed to run *inside* the linq, as linq needs to translate them to sql.

Since I can't copy paste your code with my modifications (you need to perform the date formatting **outside** the linq statement, whether using a foreach loop, or any other method).
A rough idea:

```
allclient = (from ....
             select new AllClient()
             {
              ...
              PurchaseDT = "",
              PurchaseDate = k.PurchaseDate, //the formatting will be done later
             }
foreach (AllClient c in allclient)
      c.PurchaseDT = String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", c.PurchaseDate); //or whatever other formatting you want
```

where `PurchaseDate` is of type DateTime and `PurchaseDT` is of type string.

First save the value coming from db to a datetime variable and later loop through the list using a foreach loop,convert the datetime variable into string and assign it to the string variable.

**Updated**

The only way will involve you adding one more variable to the AllClient class, if you can. This will be a DateTime to temporarily store the date, with another one as string (as shown in the code snippet above), which will be updated with the formatted date after the linq statement.

**OR**

Keep a single DateTime `PurchaseDT`, and instead of formatting it in linq or immediately afterwards, only format it when you are displaying it.
For example, if you're displaying the records on a table of some kind, while displaying the date column, do the formatting on `PurchaseDT` there.

Comment: It gives an error 'DateTime doesn't contain a definition for Value.'

Comment: Here there's again another problem.. If PurchaseDT is of type DateTime it will give an error in the LINQ. If it's a string it will give an error in foreach loop.

Comment: Updated, in the linq, give it a value of "", so you can keep it as string and still update it later.

Comment: According to your update it will try to convert empty string to string of format dd/MM/yyyy in foreach loop.

Answer (score 7):

you can check this site : [click here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

and  Basically, in entityframework has no idea how to translate an object of System.Threading.Tasks.Task to a SQL statement.you can use :

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert(dt)
```

or before using tostring(), use .tolist():

```
.ToList().select(p=>new{date=dt.ToString()});
```

Comment: you should retrieve your main columns in allclient parameter and in another parameter use allclient.tolist().select(p=>new{purchaseDt=String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}",k.PurchaseDate)});

Comment: There's no way I can get the DateTime column value as string in the PurchaseDt in allclient??

Comment: As I said before ,  EF does not know how to convert a C# method to SQL code. :(

Comment: Ok, I can have another string variable in allclient, convert and add the string date format to that variable in a foreach loop. Right?

Comment: Yes, you can use foreach loop.this is another way.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`dt.ToString("d");`

please note : the "d" format is Culture aware, but it gives you short date pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(<datetime string from db>, <format of date in Datetime string from db>, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

First you have to convert the datetime string to a DateTime object then you can Convert to required format. The overload of `ToString` you are using is valid for `DateTime` object and not for a `String` object.That's the reason for the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the View :

```
@model.RegisteredDate.ToString("dd MMMM , yyyy")
```

This will give `21 August , 2016` of Format.
If you refer `21 Aug , 2016` then just use "MMM"

Comment: Yes just Use @model.RegisteredDate.ToString("dd / MM / yyyy")